# How do I calculate accuracy from a decision tree?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I've made a decision tree and then made a confusion matrix with it:

```
tree1 <- rpart(gen_election ~ twitter + facebook + youtube, data = train_data)

pred <- factor(ifelse(predicted_values[,2] > 0.5, 1,0))

confMatTree1 <- confusionMatrix(pred, test_data$gen_election, positive = levels(test_data$gen_election)[2])
```

I'm trying to determine the accuracy of the tree.  So far I have tried this code

```
accuracyTree1 <- sum(diag(confMatTree1))/sum(confMatTree1)
```

I'm getting the error " 'list' object cannot be coerced into type 'double' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
accuracy <- confusionMatrix(pred, test_data$gen_election, 
positive = levels(test_data$gen_election)[2])$overall["Accuracy"]
```

You can see all the values stored in your `confMatTree1`, just add a $ sign and see the data associated.